# Is it a good practice to mix functional codes with unit test codes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, it is becoming much easier to perform unit test. For example, the following codes:

```
import unittest

def fun(x):
    return x + 1

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(fun(3), 4)
```

My question here is about what is the good practice of putting unit test codes in Python. In the above code, the unit test code and the production functional codes are mixed together, is it a good practice? Or should I write the test code in another file instead of mixing them together?

From my view point, I prefer to mix the functional codes with unit test because it makes code maintenance much easier.

Comment: It is an interesting question, but IMHO off topic on SO. Both approaches can be used. Separating the tests in a different source file will be more natural for Java programmers, and will be easier if you later intend to release your code as a setuptools module (for example on PyPi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started writing tests, you can simply create a file called test.py, which will contain your first test case.

You’ll find that, as you add more and more tests, your single file will become cluttered and hard to maintain, so you can create a folder called tests/ and split the tests into multiple files. It is a convention to ensure each file starts with test_ so all test runners will assume that Python file contains tests to be executed. Some very large projects split tests into more subdirectories based on their purpose or usage.

Comment: You could add this also makes continuous integration quite easy

Answer (score 0):

That I know it's fine for single-file libraries, but when a library grows beyond a single file tests *usually* get moved to their own folder.